# duplicate feature with same data in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

*this is not a duplicated question*
What happens if I train a model on a data set that includes a duplicated feature?
we have some feature such as x(1) and the label is y(1).
we add a new feature that its data is clearly similarity to x(1).
what happen if we train a model with this {x(1), x(1), y(1)} feature instead of {x(1), y(1)}.
does any change in logistic regression efficiency? What changes performance?